# How do you unset a NODE_OPTION in cmd line

Tags: node.js, bash, ssl, cmd, openssl

I was having trouble setting up my PC environment and couldn't find a fix, then unwittingly executed the following command:

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

And thus whenever I try to run `code .` I get the following error:

```
C:\xx\xx\xx\xx\xx\Microsoft VS Code\bin\..\Code.exe: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
```

A github user suggested to use the `unset` command but I also get an error when I attempt to use it as being an unrecognized command.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

`set NODE_OPTIONS=""` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`NODE_OPTIONS=""` (with out the set) worked for me. Could be a mac thing.

Answer (score 1):

To run this Command in windows 11 cmd.
Just run this command

$env:NODE_OPTIONS=""

Comment: That's PowerShell. In `cmd`/batch, it would be `set "NODE_OPTIONS="`